# Is this induction proof correctly stated/sufficient?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

I am currently taking a Real Analysis course and it's my first experience writing my own proofs. I'm a little concerned with whether or not something like the following would be sufficient on a typically graded exam.

$$\forall n\in \mathbb{N}, 3+11+\cdots+(8n-5) = 4n^{2}-n$$

$$P(1) = 3 = 4(1^{2})-1 = 3    True$$

$$P(n+1) = 3+11+\cdots+(8n-5)+[8(n+1)-5] = 4n^{2}-n+[8(n+1)-5]$$
$$=4n^{2}-n+(8n+8-5)$$
$$=4n^{2}-n+8n+3$$
$$=4n^{2}+8n+4-n-1$$
$$=4(n^{2}+2n+1)-n-1$$
$$=4(n+1)^{2}-(n+1)$$

Comment: You shouldn't use $=$ for statements, as in $P(1) = 3 = 4(1^2)-1$.  That makes it look like $P$ is a function, $P(1) = 3$, and $3 = 4(1^2)-1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proofs are generally much better when they include a brief explanation of what you're doing, instead of just a sequence of symbols and equations. It might seem less "mathy" to make it more of an essay, but it makes it infinitely easier to read and understand. You should also state *why* things are true, such as when you use your induction hypothesis.

But logically, it's sound.